# session variable becoming null after webResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am making a email template and this template will be send to the multiple users and in this template there is only a gridview control and I will fill the grid with a session variable, Session variable is having the datatable.

My issue is this when i am using the "WebResponse" for this page then i do not get the session value that is null.(i have cross check that my session Name is same);

code Snippet:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strFullUrl);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

what i am doing wrong, Please give some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Sessions` does not persist with `HttpWebResponse`.
Create the helper class called `CookieContainer` and attach it with your `web request`.

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
WebRequest request = (WebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strFullUrl);
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

WebResponse response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: How can i read the session value because it is still null? I'll have to read the cookie?

Comment: You can use the `cookieContainer` container to pass the `session cookie`.